# How to remote debug a Win32 VCL application built with runtime package

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, remote-debugging

I wrote a simple VCL win32 application that has the following code:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('bingo');
end;
```

I compiled the application with runtime packages and has turn on the following switches:

1. Debug Information -> true
2. Include remote debug symbol -> true
3. Assertion, debug information, local smbols, use debug dcus -> true

The output has the following files:

1. Project1.exe
2. project1.rsm

The two runtime packages are:

1. vcl160.bpl
2. rtl160.bpl

I set a break point in Button1Click handler, the local IDE debugger will stop there if I run the 
application in debugger mode.

Next, I want to try remote debug the application with runtime packages.

I assign remote profile to the 32-bits windows platform. The test connection works with the remote profile. PAServer was started too in remote machine.  I can notice 4 files were copied to remote machine when attempt to run the application with Delphi XE2 IDE debugger:

1. Project1.exe
2. project1.rsm
3. vcl160.bpl
4. rtl160.bpl

However, the event log shows:

```
Module Load: Project1.exe. No Debug Info. Base Address: $00400000. Process Project1.exe (1676)
```

As the module doesn't has debug info, all breakpoint will fail to trigger.

I have tried build single file .exe application without runtime packages.  The same remote debugger steps work and I can debug application remotely.

What has make the remote debugging fail with application built with runtime packages?

Comment: a good practice to debug is also to use OutputDebugString, which can pe handled by you, or by a 3d party software

Comment: because you did not specify the Delphi version, maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018147/delphi-2010-remote-debugging-unable-to-get-breakpoints-working

Comment: RBA: I am using Delphi XE2 update 4.  The post you suggested is standalone .exe application and not compiled with runtime packages.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang - have you tried the link from SO?

Comment: @RBA: Yes. I have tried the link you gave.  As I said, standalone .EXE application works but runtime packages apps doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to additionaly deploy '.dcp' files corresponding to used runtime packages.

From [Debugger Notes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Release_Notes_for_XE2#Debugger_Notes) (Release Notes for XE2):

> **Ensure Debug Information by Adding .dcp Files to Application
>   Deployment**
>
> If your Delphi application links with run-time packages, the expected
>   debug information might not be generated. This is true for Mac OS X
>   applications and for remote Win64 or remote Win32 applications. The
>   workaround is to use the Deployment Manager to add the .dcp files that
>   correspond to the run-time packages in your run-time package list. For
>   instance, if you are using rtl, you must deploy the rtl.dcp file.
>
> Use the .dcp files located in the Embarcadero\Rad Studio\9.0\lib
>   directories, as follows:
>
> - For an OS X application: Embarcadero\Rad Studio\9.0\lib\osx\release
> - For a remote 64-bit Windows application: Embarcadero\Rad Studio\9.0\lib\win64\release
> - For a remote 32-bit Windows application: Embarcadero\Rad Studio\9.0\lib\win32\release

Comment: Follow the debugger note instruction doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: @Chau - Sorry, no. Actually I never used runtime packages. I was hoping that the documentation was helpful. Would it make a difference with the 'dcp's in the debug folder?

Comment: @Sectac: I have tried both release and debug folder and it doesn't work.